# C# nest elasticsearch converting guid into array

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sFj0.png)I am doing an aggregation on a field with the a guid value like c4b0c9ae-345c-4247-87e3-e9d9de67c01b but when elastic search returns the aggregations
it is becoming an array ["c4b0c9ae","345c","4247","87e3","e9d9de67c01b"].
How do you handle this on nest?

Comment: can you provide what you have so far?

Comment: Added the link to the image on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field has been mapped as a [`text` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) which undergoes analysis at index time, by default using the [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). The result is that the GUID is tokenized into the constituent parts by splitting on hyphens. You can see this for yourself using the Analyze API (in Kibana Console)

```
GET _analyze
{
    "analyzer": "standard",
    "text": ["c4b0c9ae-345c-4247-87e3-e9d9de67c01b"]
}
```

yields

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "c4b0c9ae",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 8,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "345c",
         "start_offset": 9,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "4247",
         "start_offset": 14,
         "end_offset": 18,
         "type": "<NUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "87e3",
         "start_offset": 19,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "e9d9de67c01b",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 36,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

You probably don't want to analyze GUIDs at index time, so you should [explicitly map them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/mapping.html) as [keyword datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html).